# Does retagging count as editing?

Tags: support

In terms of badges such as Copy Editor, does using the "retag" button on a question count as making an edit?

Comment: Short Answer: No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this question on meta.stackoverflow: [Does retagging a question count as an edit for Strunk & White?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28454/does-retagging-a-question-count-as-an-edit) and this question: [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges/445#445)

Answer (score 0):

Retagging is just changing the tags, not making a change to the post body. So a retag is not counted as an edit.

Comment: You can't earn rep from meta.SF; but thank you for restating what others have already said.